# How can I get single element of the array in PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

Now I get all results of the array together using PDO. How can I choose this or that single element of the array(like array[3]).

```
  $title_select_query= $dbh -> prepare("SELECT title FROM books WHERE id = :id   ORDER BY date DESC");
            $title_select_query ->execute(array(':id' => $id));
            $title_select_query_result = $title_select_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ( $title_select_query_result as $row)
        {
             echo $row['title']; 
        }
             $title_select_query=null;
```

Unexpectedly found a solution like this

```
 $hmm[]=$row['title'];
      echo($hmm[0]);
```

So, the question now is wether it's okay?

Comment: if you don't want a associative index, then use the numeric index flag `PDO::FETCH_NUM`, then access `[0]` and everything else. not providing a flag on `->fetchAll()` will fetch both associative and numeric indices.

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php

Comment: if that ID is unique, and if found, then just `->fetch()` once, assign that and you'll get that `[0]`